# PowerBI dashboard to be emailed as a PDF on trigger from MS Forms submission

Tags: automation, powerbi, onedrive, ms-forms

I am trying to get a survey response plotted on a Powerbi page. Survey questionnaire is built in MS Forms, response values get stored in an Excel on OneDrive and are piped in as a dataset into a PowerBI app which plots this data. What I am trying to achieve is that once the respondent submits this questionnaire, the PowerBI report gets emailed as a PDF file to the respondent (I ask for the email in the questionnaire and it is present in the dataset).

I was not able to find any option in MS Flows to allow email of PowerBI PDF on submission of MS Forms questionnaire. Are there any options that I may try out to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to use Power Automate (Flow) or the Power BI API to programmatically generate a PDF from a report. It will be in [public preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2019wave2/business-intelligence/api-export-report-powerpoint-pdf-jpeg) from Feb 2020 for **Power BI Embedded only**. It will export to PDF, PowerPoint and JPEG.

What you will have to do is, call the Power BI Embedded REST API from Power Automate (flow), save the file to a location. Then email that file out to your form user again using Power Automate.

Hope this helps